What early juvenile sci-fi book is about a boy who trains on a lunar station for a mission in space?
I have vague memories of reading this in the late 70's or early 80's so the details are pretty fuzzy.
What I do recall is that it was about a teenage boy who was training for some kind of mission, maybe exploration, maybe combat - for some reason, I'm thinking the mission was to be on Jupiter. Part of the training involved doing hazardous jumps across a low-gravity part of the station on the moon (à la Ender's Game).
I was thinking it might have been Heinlein, Asimov, or Arthur Clark... seems like I was reading them a lot in that time frame. I'm pretty sure it was targeted at juvenile readers more so than adults.
If I think of more data points, I'll add them, but maybe this is enough to trigger some ideas.

Heinlein's Space Cadet is an early (1948) juvenile novel about a lad training for the Space Patrol, but as I recall he trains on a space station , not on the moon. A classic but probably not the one you're looking for. More data points might help to narrow it down.

Wow! First tip and it's a winner. Make it an answer and I'll accept it. It turns out that the story's about a guy who joins up with the Interplanetary Patrol. Chapter 7 - To Make a Spaceman, talks about a "free-fall gymnasium". Oh and two of his buddies are from Venus and Jupiter, but that's not where they went... a mission to an asteroid belt near Mars.

He doesn't train on the moon, but it's Space Cadet by Robert A. Heinlein, which was also the answer to the old question Name of sci fi book where academy entrance exam is "impossible". Does any of these covers ring a bell? It can be borrowed (for free but registration required) from the Internet Archive.
Wikipedia plot summary:

In 2075, teenager Matt Dodson applies to join the prestigious Interplanetary Patrol. After a number of physical, mental, and ethics tests, he is accepted as a cadet. He makes friends with fellow recruits William "Tex" Jarman, Venus-born Oscar Jensen, and Pierre Armand from Ganymede. His first roommate is Girard Burke, the arrogant son of a wealthy spaceship builder. They are transported to the orbiting school ship PRS James Randolph for further training. Burke eventually either resigns or is asked to leave, and goes into the merchant service, but the remainder do well enough to be assigned to working Patrol ships.
Dodson, Jarman and Jensen ship out on the Aes Triplex. Their first real mission is to help search for a missing research vessel, the Pathfinder, in the asteroid belt. They find it, but all aboard are dead, the unlucky victims of a fast-moving object that punctured the ship when the armored outer airlock door was open. Before the accident, a researcher on the Pathfinder had found evidence that the planet which blew up to form the asteroids was inhabited by an intelligent species, and that the explosion had been artificial. The captain of the Aes Triplex transfers half the crew to the repaired Pathfinder so that they can take the ship and the news of the startling discovery back to Earth quickly. With the remainder (including all three cadets), he plots a slower, fuel-efficient, elliptical voyage back to Earth.
Then, he receives an urgent message to investigate an incident on Venus. He sends Lieutenant Thurlow and the cadets to the planet's surface. The lander touches down on a sinkhole, giving the crew barely enough time to get out before it disappears in the mud. With Thurlow comatose, injured when the lander fell over, Jensen assumes command. He contacts the sentient, usually friendly Venerians, but the entire party is taken captive. They soon find out why.
These particular natives had never seen human beings before, until old classmate Burke showed up in a prospecting ship. He had taken the matriarch of the local clan hostage when she refused to give him permission to exploit a rich deposit of radioactive ores. The locals promptly attacked the ship and killed his crew; Burke managed to send a message for help before being taken prisoner.
Jensen gains the matriarch's trust and convinces her that they are honorable and civilized, unlike Burke, and the Patrolmen are released. Unfortunately, neither the lander nor Burke's ship is flightworthy. To their amazement, the matriarch takes the stranded humans to the carefully preserved Astarte, the legendary first ship to set out for Venus over a century before and thought to have been lost en route. According to the log, the crew perished from disease. With the help of the natives, the cadets recommission the ship and fly it back to Venus's South Pole colony. Dodson is initially disappointed when they are not treated as heroes, but then realizes that what they accomplished was simply what was expected of Patrolmen.


I also wondered if it might be Space Cadet but didn't have my computer last night...hate typing on the mobile phone.  ;)
Just for the sake of completeness, adding one similar book that I would have suggested as a candidate.  Similar publication time and some similarities of plot (free fall training of young man) and also by a "Big Three" author:  Islands in the Sky, by Clarke.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islands_in_the_Sky
It's a fun read...similar enjoyment to Space Cadet.  SC is maybe slightly superior (although not perfect itself...that would come with Red Planet).  But if you liked SC, give IITS a try also!

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How does Islands in the Sky match the question?  Was there low-g (not zero-g) training on the Moon for a mission to Jupiter?

It was no G, as I recall, including some games/sports in no G.   The reason I thought of each was the emphasis on training (is most of the plot of each novel).  But in any case, neither novel matches exactly, yet each has some aspects (big three, teenage boy, space training emphasized)

FWIW, both books have the majority of the training in orbit, free fall, not the moon (unlike the title of the question).  In Space Cadet it is a "school ship" near the main transit satellite.  In Islands it is a space station satellite.  There is a moon episode within Space Cadet, which matches the question, but is very small part of the training.
